# Disable Background touch in popup dialog in android

Tags: android

[image]In my code i am showing alert in popup view. but when i touch any background buttons, they are enable. i want to disable background touch.
follwoing is my code. please check it.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popuplayoutReject = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_reject_request, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
final PopupWindow popUpReject = new PopupWindow(popuplayoutReject, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
ImageButton btnPopupReject_Ok, btnPopUpReject_Cancel;
TextView txtRequestRejectMessage = (TextView) popuplayoutReject.findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);
txtRequestRejectMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.AddEntryNotSaved));
btnPopupReject_Ok = (ImageButton) popuplayoutReject.findViewById(R.id.btnPopup_Yes);
btnPopupReject_Ok.setImageResource(R.drawable.yes_button);

btnPopupReject_Ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();
    }
});

btnPopUpReject_Cancel = (ImageButton) popuplayoutReject.findViewById(R.id.btnPopUp_No);
btnPopUpReject_Cancel.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_button);
btnPopUpReject_Cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popUpReject.dismiss();
    }
});
popUpReject.showAtLocation(popuplayoutReject, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Comment: is that a default dialog or custom..??

Comment: Try with `popUpReject.setOutsideTouchable(false);`

Comment: @m0skit0 I have tried but not succeed

Comment: What you tried exactly and why it did not succeed? Any errors? And btw, what you want to do is done way easier using [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) instead.

Comment: @m0skit0 : I have tried popUpReject.setOutsideTouchable(false); and make WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT in Height and width. its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just done with implementing

```
final PopupWindow popUpReject = new PopupWindow(popuplayoutReject, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, false);
                    popUpReject.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Comment: You answer your own question with my comment-answer? Amazing way of having people not answer your questions anymore ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 : Really thanks for your answer but Please see that i have answered your comment. but it was partially true. what i have done is, i have put both layout params as Fill parent, then it gets success. and i have also voted your comment as useful buddy.;-0

Answer (score -1):

### Your code

```
 final PopupWindow popUpReject = new PopupWindow(popuplayoutReject, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
```

### Fixed code

```
 final PopupWindow popUpReject = new PopupWindow(popuplayoutReject, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
```